# Check which thread is active in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am running 15 different threads for which thread definitions are instantiated through a class. I would like to know how I can check on other threads from within a thread.

For instance, before running thread *n* (provided *n* > 1 and *n* < 15), I want to check if thread (*n* - 1) and (*n* + 1) are running. If they are running, then I do not want to run thread *n*.

Answer (score 1):

`t.isAlive()` returns `True` if `t` is still running. Ref: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive

`threading.enumerate()` ["Return[s] a list of all Thread objects currently alive."](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate)

Each thread has a `name` attribute that can be set on creation of the thread (via the constructor), and read or changed at any given time: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much context into the problem you are trying to solve, but it seems what you are looking for is a semaphore.

### References

Semaphores in Python:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects